# C++ Compilation Problems with Microsoft Visual Studios 2010 Beta 1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compilation

Well, I just got the new MSVS 2010 Beta 1, and just like with 2008 express, I just can't figure out how to compile anything, not even a simple hello world program. Anyone have any pointers? I usually just get a blanket fail message. No real information.

Edit: Sorry about that

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    cout << "hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

I go to build and I get:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: forkicks, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>
> 1>Embedding manifest...
>
> 1>.\Debug\forkicks.exe.intermediate.manifest : general error c1010070: Failed to load and parse the manifest. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> 1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\Randy\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\forkicks\forkicks\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
>
> 1>forkicks - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

That is 2008

```
1>------ Build started: Project: For Kicks, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 7/22/2009 9:36:39 PM.
1>_PrepareForBuild:
1>  Creating directory "Debug\".
1>  Creating "Debug\lastbuild.timestamp" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>ClCompile:
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users\randy\documents\visual studio 10\projects\for kicks\main.cpp(5): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.63
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

is 2010. I create a win32 project, name it, etc. Right click on source file, add a C++ file with no headers or anything. Just a blank document.

New 2010:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: hoyeah, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 7/22/2009 10:03:35 PM.
1>_PrepareForBuild:
1>  Creating directory "Debug\".
1>  Creating "Debug\lastbuild.timestamp" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>PrepareForBuild:
1>  Creating directory "C:\Users\Randy\Desktop\C++ Programs\hoyeah\Debug\".
1>ClCompile:
1>  test.cpp
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.1.7000.0
1>  
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>  
1>  
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\Randy\Desktop\C++ Programs\hoyeah\Debug\hoyeah.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.25
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Edit #2. How exactly would I go about changing it to multibyte?

Comment: I use it daily. Please be more precise - what, exactly, is the error message you're getting? Give some specific steps to reproduce it, and describe the behavior you observe.

Comment: Can you reedit you post with the new build information after you have fixed main() to be int main() ?

Answer (score 5):

[That's a well known problem with VS10 Beta](http://virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=252). You need to change the default encoding to Multibyte from Unicode to make it work.

Comment: Where do I find the setting though?

Comment: Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > General > Character Set

Answer (score 3):

**int main()** maybe ?

Try also changing the destination of the project to something simpler and not that long since I believe I also had the same error when the destination was too long.

Also did you choose a console application when creating the project?

If that didn't help, google gave this as possible answers too :

- "You could try going to your
  project's Properties > Configuration
  Properties > Manifest Tool > Input
  and Output, and set your "Embed
  Manifest" option to "No"."
- "I had a similar problem like this a
  few months ago and I solved it by
  going to project -> properties ->
  Configuration Properties -> General
  -> Character set. Under character set I changed it to Use Multi-Byte
  Character Set and then my compliment
  issue went away."

Edit:

In regard to the latest error link [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=454646) directly from microsoft. I'm afraid that from this point on it's google time as I'm all out of ideas if it doesn't work.

The link says : "As a workaround for Beta1 you can change the entry point to use "wmain" instead of "main" or change the character set of your project to use "Multi-Byte Character Set""

Easiest would be to just change the name of main to wmain then.

Comment: Ok, got it to work as a CLR console application in 2008. But, I can't get it to work on the win32 console application. Tried in main(). Moved the directory to desktop/folder

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it to compile using a win32 console ap, changing to Multibyte, and using the following code:

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Now to try to figure something else out. I'm not used to VS so...

Thanks everyone.